# How to round up Buffer result to 2 decimal places with TOSCA automation?

Tags: automated-tests, tosca

I have to verify a number is equal to the result of multiplying 2 other numbers.
Number to verify is "19.91" and the multiplication result is "19.905".
I need to find a way to convert "19.905" to "19.91"

Example: [A=B*C]
Buffer "A" is the number to Verify
Buffer "Calculation" is the result of multiplication  of [B*C]

```
    Buffer values, [A = 19.91] and [Calculation = 19.905]
```

To round the buffer value of "Calculation" I used,
{MATH[Round({B[Calculation]},2)]} which gives me "19.9"
and
{MATH[Round({B[Calculation]},3)]} which gives me "19.905"
This also not making sense why 2 is giving me result with 1 dacimal place, where 3 is giving me 3 decimal place as expected!

How do I make it "19.91" ?

Please Help !